# Unity desktop environment and Georgian (MESS) layout

Tags: unity, unity-dash, unity-2d, hud, unity-greeter

I've installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my laptop with Unity desktop environment. I'm Georgian and often use Georgian (MESS) layout on keyboard. When I use LibreOffice and Georgian (MESS) layout in Unity environment, shortcut keys like: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> etc. don't work. Does someone know the reason of this problem and way(s) to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to solve the problem:

1. Open LibreOffice writer
2. click `Tools`.
3. In Tools click `Customize..`
   [image]
4. This window will open 
   [image]
5. Find and select your shortcut key in the `Shortcut keys`, like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
6. In the `Category` window select Edit and in the `Function` select copy
7. Click `Modify`
8. Press`Ok` button [image]

Now <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works.
Do these steps for all the shortcuts you want. 
I don't know the reason of the problem.

I hope that my answer will help.